# translate from SQL to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

i have the following sql script.

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN possession
ON movies.id = possession.movie_id
AND possession.master_id = ?
WHERE possession.id is NULL
ORDER BY movies.id DESC
```

and need help to illustrate in sqlalchemy.
Please can someone help me?

The following doesn't work:

```
movies = movie.Movie.query.join(possession.Possession, movie.Movie.id == possession.Possession.movie_id)\
            .filter(possession.Possession.master_id == session.get('userId'))\
            .filter(not_(possession.Possession.id)).order_by(movie.Movie.id.desc()).all()
```

Thank you very much!

Cheers

Comment: You have `master_id` in your SQL query, but `user_id` in your SQLAlchemy query. Is that intentional?

Comment: It's the same... sorry! :-) But i changed it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to translate your SQL query is the ORM query below:

```
qry = (session.query(Movie)
        .outerjoin(Possession, and_(Movie.id == Possession.movie_id, Possession.master_id == master_id))
        .filter(Possession.id == None)
        .order_by(desc(Movie.id))
        )
movies = qry.all()
```

produces:

```
SELECT movies.id AS movies_id, movies.name AS movies_name
FROM movies LEFT OUTER JOIN possessions ON movies.id = possessions.movie_id AND possessions.master_id = :master_id_1
WHERE possessions.id IS NULL ORDER BY movies.id DESC
```

I also think this would be the faster implementation compared to an alternative of using [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) (see below), which is more concise, but the `SQL` it produces is not. This also assumes there is a relationship `Movie.possessions = relationship(Possession)`:

```
qry = (session.query(Movie)
        .filter(~Movie.possessions.any(Possession.master_id == master_id))
        .order_by(desc(Movie.id))
        )
movies = qry.all()
```

produces:

```
SELECT movies.id AS movies_id, movies.name AS movies_name
FROM movies
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM possessions
WHERE movies.id = possessions.movie_id AND possessions.master_id = :master_id_1)) ORDER BY movies.id DESC
```